# Impractical vs Impracticable

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

What is the difference between *impractical* and *impracticable*? The former is the word with which I am familiar.

The dictionary definition seems to indicate that impracticable relates to the inability to accomplish something rather than the merits of doing so. However, other grammatical references, such as [Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/impractical-vs-impracticable/), indicate that "Impracticable is a synonym of impractical in the definition of being unfeasible or impossible to use."

Is this a matter of degrees, or is there a clear difference?

Comment: What did the dictionary tell you?

Comment: I've reviewed the dictionary definition but also web sites such as http://grammarist.com/usage/impractical-vs-impracticable/ which indicate that they are actually partially synonymous.

Comment: I've updated my question to better reflect the uncertainty I have.

Answer (score 6):

> #### Impractical
>
> - Not practical : not wise to put into or keep in practice or effect
>
> *"Playing basketball is impractical because there is a hurricane outside."*

([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impractical))

> #### Impracticable
>
> - Not practicable : incapable of being performed or accomplished by the means employed or at command; impossible
>
> *"Playing basketball is impracticable because we do not have a basketball or a hoop."*

([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impracticable))

Basically, ***Impracticable*** is something that cannot be **practiced** with what you have at your command, while ***Impractical*** is something that is unwise to practice.

I do agree that they are synonyms, but I do not think they are generally interchangeable and there is a clear difference in the most common usages.

Comment: +1 agree. impractical things can still be practiced, but aren't recommended. like building a stupid border wall for example.

Answer (score 0):

In drafting contacts and similar legal language, I would use the word "Impracticable" to convey a weaker meaning of "not easy, or awkward to make happen, or inconvenient," while the word "impractical" would sometimes be used to convey a stronger meaning that is almost equivalent to "impossible."

Comment: According to the dictionary you have the terms flipped.   impractical = difficult  |  impracticable = impossible in practice